# JSON Object Parsing Error

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have got the following string as HTTPResponse. It is in JSON format.

```
  [
    {
       "From":"en",
       "OriginalTextSentenceLengths":[
          5
       ],
       "TranslatedText":"Hallo",
       "TranslatedTextSentenceLengths":[
          5
       ]
    },
    {
       "From":"en",
       "OriginalTextSentenceLengths":[
          8
       ],
       "TranslatedText":"Frage",
       "TranslatedTextSentenceLengths":[
          5
       ]
   },
   {
       "From":"en",
       "OriginalTextSentenceLengths":[
          6
       ],
       "TranslatedText":"Antwort",
       "TranslatedTextSentenceLengths":[
          7
       ]
  }
]
```

So this string I am parsing as follows to get the "Translated Texts array"

```
  String resp = "[{\"From\":\"en\",\"OriginalTextSentenceLengths\":[5],\"TranslatedText\":\"Hallo\",\"TranslatedTextSentenceLengths\":[5]},{\"From\":\"en\",\"OriginalTextSentenceLengths\":[8],\"TranslatedText\":\"Frage\",\"TranslatedTextSentenceLengths\":[5]},{\"From\":\"en\",\"OriginalTextSentenceLengths\":[6],\"TranslatedText\":\"Antwort\",\"TranslatedTextSentenceLengths\":[7]}]";

    String[] stringArray = null;
    try {
    JSONArray finalResult=null;
    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(resp); 

        finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
        stringArray = new String[finalResult.length()];

    for(int i=0;i<finalResult.length();i++){
        JSONObject e = finalResult.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.v("TAG",e.getString("TranslatedText"));
        stringArray[i]=e.getString("TranslatedText");
    }        

    }catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting the extracted "translated text" array ( Hallo, Frage, Antwort) out of the JSON Object...

But when I am doing the same procedure by giving the same string as input to JSONTokener directly i.e after getting HttpResponse as below, I am **getting JSON Exception at       finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener) line....**

**org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of**

```
String resp = getHttpResponse(uri);
String[] stringArray = null;
    try {
    JSONArray finalResult=null;
    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(resp); 

        finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
        stringArray = new String[finalResult.length()];

    for(int i=0;i<finalResult.length();i++){
        JSONObject e = finalResult.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.v("TAG",e.getString("TranslatedText"));
        stringArray[i]=e.getString("TranslatedText");
    }

    }catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have tried hard for 2 days to resolve this error but couldn't do it.. So I am posting it here... Please help

**EDIT:**

I am adding the implementation of getHttpResponse

```
 public static String getHttpResponse(URI uri) {
    Log.d("APP_TAG", "Going to make a get request");
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet();
        get.setURI(uri);
        //DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams(); 
        int timeoutConnection = 30000; 
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection); 
        int timeoutSocket = 30000; 
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket); 

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters); 

        Log.v("TAG","1");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
        Log.v("TAG","2");
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Log.d("demo", "HTTP Get succeeded");

            HttpEntity messageEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream is = messageEntity.getContent();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("demo", e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.d("demo", "Done with HTTP getting");
    return response.toString();
}
```

And the uri which I am giving to getHttpResponse is as follows

```
   String[] texts = {"hello","question","answer"};
   final String params = "appId=" +   URLEncoder.encode("78280AF4DFA1CE1676AFE86340C690023A5AC139","UTF-8")                 
            + "&from=" + URLEncoder.encode("en","UTF-8")                 
            + "&to=" + URLEncoder.encode("de","UTF-8")                 
            + "&texts=" +   URLEncoder.encode(buildStringArrayParam(texts),"UTF-8");                

     final URL url = new  URL("http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/TranslateArray?" + params);       

     URI myURI = java.net.URI.create(url.toString()); 
     String resp = getHttpResponse(myURI);
```

This response string is what I am trying to parse...

This is for buildStringArrayParam(texts)

```
StringBuilder targetString = new StringBuilder("[\""); 
    String value;
    for(Object obj : values) {
        if(obj!=null) {
            value = obj.toString();
            if(value.length()!=0) {
                if(targetString.length()>2)
                    targetString.append(",\"");
                targetString.append(value);
                targetString.append("\"");
            }
        }
    }
    targetString.append("]");
    return targetString.toString();
```

Comment: If you log the `resp` string from `getHttpResponse()`, does it actually contain the JSON string you expect?

Comment: Yes it contains the JSON string I expect...

Comment: Did you check that with `equals()`, comparing it your `String resp = "[{\"From\":\"...` constant? Could you add the `resp` you get from `getHttpResponse()` to you question?

Comment: Also, it might help to see your implementaton of `getHttpResponse()`.

Comment: Added implementation of 'getHttpResponse()' function...

Comment: You're currently ignoring any character encoding sent by the server. Try to use `String response = EntityUtils.toString(messageEntity);` instead of rolling your own with `InputStreamReader`. It's much less code and much more robust.

Comment: Also, you might want to use [`BasicHttpParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/params/BasicHttpParams.html) and pass that to `HttpGet.setParams()` -- this will take care of all the URL encoding/escaping, so you don't have to. Don't add it all to the URL and encode it yourself.

Comment: I used 'EntityUtils.toString(messageEntity);' but even then I am getting the same error...!!

Comment: What's the exact value of myUri right before you pass it to getHttpResponse()? Does that URL return what you expect when you open it in a browser?

Comment: displaying myURI.toString() in logcat gave this output http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/TranslateArray?appId=78280AF4DFA1CE1676AFE86340C690023A5AC139&from=en&to=de&texts=%5B%22hello%22%2C%22question%22%2C%22answer%22%5D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10209/discussion-between-dsp-and-philipp-reichart)  @phillip discussion was automatically moved to chat..

Comment: The URL returned exactly what I expected when I opened it in a browser.

Comment: Check out my answer, I think I found the... crazy reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahaha... Microsoft.

At least in this case, they serve their API responses with an (incorrect?) `FEFF FEFF` UTF-16 [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning which breaks most clients.

Like [the PHP guys over here already found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967190/decoding-the-json-output-from-microsoft-translator-api-with-php/7128250#7128250), you just have to strip the first two bytes from the response. For exmaple in your code:

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(resp.substring(2));
```

I'm afraid the more harmless `trim()` doesn't work.

It's really hard to find, because `FEFF`'s official name is "zero width no-break space" so it's completely invisible unless you look at your string as char array or notice how your text cursor stops when you move through a string using left/right arrow keys...

Note that you should not do this with any other HTTP response you receive, this is just for this Microsoft API (maybe others, too).

Comment: Hi, got a new exception now....org.json.JSONException: Value {"TranslatedText":"Hallo","TranslatedTextSentenceLengths":[5],"OriginalTextSentenceLengths":[5],"From":"en"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: This occured at JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(resp.substring(2)); line...

Comment: Try with `substring(1)` instead. I'm not sure if it worked with 2 for me because of the API returning a different BOM sometimes or my test case being wrong.

Comment: Worst case, the API returns different BOMs at will and you have to try with substring(1) and substring(2) and pick whatever JSON can understand.

Comment: Hi Philipp, you are truly awesome....!!!!! I changed it to 1, and it worked... :) Thanks a lot for finding this crazy reason...!! :)

Answer (score 2):

[Try GSON](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

And try to change your code design, hope it will help you.

And retrieve content from url -

```
public static String getContent(String url) throws Exception {
    return(new Scanner(new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream()).useDelimiter("/z").next());
}
```

Have fun...

Comment: I can use GSON but the main thing which is bugging me is that, when JSON parsing is working in the 1st part , why it is failing in the second part?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
InputStream content = httpEntity.getContent();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content,"iso-8859-1"),8);
String resp = reader.readLine();
```

Now "resp" will hold the string which can be parsed...

Comment: Actually the problem is not with HttpResponse because I am getting the response string correctly and I displayed it in the logcat...I used that string in the first code which I posted and it worked...

Comment: your URL support POST/GET HTTP method? check that once again!

Comment: It supports GET because I have already got the response which I posted in the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

```
After getting the HTTP Response you have to do this thing, you cant use Httpresponse directly.

HttpResponse response= null;
response = http.execute(get);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String xmlstring = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
message = xmlstring;
```