# Microsoft Translator HTTP JSON?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Translator API. I'm currently using the HTTP API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512419.aspx

Looks like all the examples shown have XML content and responses. I've seen some old stackoverflow posts with JSON references like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967190/decoding-the-json-output-from-microsoft-translator-api-with-php) but can't find anything on that in the MS documentation. Is it possible to make requests and get responses to the API in JSON, and is this documented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nope! It's still not possible with Microsoft Translator API to be used in json! It's so weird...

Take a look here: http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/get_Translate

The Response Content Type shows only "application/xml" as the only option!